# What is the maximum amount of data that can be returned from a sproc in sql server to ADO.NET application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

We have a windows service that needs to retrieve all the Orders of a Customer. There can be cases where a customer can have large number of Orders. So wanted to know if there was a known limit on the size of data that can be returned from a sproc in SQL Server to ADO.NET application. I can then calculate the average size of row in the table and provide the max Orders per customer limit.
Thanks.

Comment: There is no limit to the number of rows that can be returned.

Comment: When I say large number of Orders, I mean, something like 1 million. Will this also work?

Comment: @NullSkull90 Did you look at my answer below? DataReader "technically" supports max data types. You should obviously do some testing.

Comment: There is no row limit.  The maximum size of a SQL Server database is, if I recall correctly apprx 500,000 ***terabytes***. You are nowhere near that, plus, there *is no limit* to the number of rows returned.  Your interface method might have a limit, but if you are using a .Net streaming method like datareaders, the only limit is your time and patience. (and your client's memory or storage if you are trying to retain them all at once)

Comment: @WilliamXifaras The OP is asking about row limits, not column size limit.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Understood, which is why I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I cannot repeat this enough: ***There is no row limit.***

The maximum size of a SQL Server database is, if I recall correctly apprx 500,000 **terabytes**. You are nowhere near that, plus, ***there is no limit to the number of rows returned***. Your interface method *might* have a limit, but if you are using a .Net streaming method like a `datareader`, the only limit is your time and patience (and your client's memory or storage if you are trying to retain them all at once).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ADO.NET, DataReader supports the max data types. You will have to use a batching strategy if you are dealing with massive result sets.

> Large object (LOB) data types are those that exceed the maximum row size of 8 kilobytes (KB). SQL Server provides a max specifier for varchar, nvarchar, and varbinary data types to allow storage of values as large as 2^32 bytes. Table columns and Transact-SQL variables may specify varchar(max), nvarchar(max), or varbinary(max) data types. **In ADO.NET, the max data types can be fetched by a DataReader**, and can also be specified as both input and output parameter values without any special handling. For large varchar data types, data can be retrieved and updated incrementally.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399384(v=vs.110).aspx

I just found following SO post which is also relevant.

[SQL Server and SqlDataReader - Trillion Records - Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849144/sql-server-and-sqldatareader-trillion-records-memory)